# Disable "implicitly captured closure" with comment

Tags: c#, .net, resharper

How can I disable the "implicitly captured closure" inspection hint in Resharper with a comment?

To make it more specific: I know what this warning means and I also know that I could rewrite the code to make it go I way. But I would like to know whether it is also possible with a specific comment that targets only this inspection hint. Resharper is not not giving me the option in the Alt+Enter context menu. I use Resharper 8.2 in Visual Studio 2013.